# How to have a loop inside SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

Ok I have the below command which fetches me a set of data with some order number. The problem is when the set of data is more than one, the order value remains same instead of auto incrementing.

For Example:

If I fetch data one by one the **Order** value increment in the table as per the below logic, but if there is more than one data fetched at a time the order remains same i.e it auto increments for all the row fetched with same value. Maybe somekind of loop where I fetch data and update one by one can help me in this. Help me in implementing the looping/array condition in my stored procedure. My command are as follow:

```
declare @MaxOrder1 int=0

select @MaxOrder1 = max([order]) from [dbo].[XYZ_ABC_Table1] where [Id]=@Id
if (@MaxOrder1 is null)
begin

set @MaxOrder1 =0
end
set @MaxOrder1 = @MaxOrder1+1

UPDATE STPC SET STPC.[IsIncluded]= PT.[Value] FROM [dbo].[XYZ_ABC_Table1] STPC  join @Table2 PT on (PT.Id = STPC.Id)  
   UPDATE STPC SET STPC.[Order]= case
                  when STPC.[IsIncluded] = 1 then @MaxOrder1
                  else ''
                  END
                  FROM [dbo].[XYZ_ABC_Table1] STPC  join @Table2 PT on (PT.Id = STPC.Id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @MaxOrder1 int=0
declare @MinOrder int=0
select top 1 @MaxOrder1 =  [order] from [dbo].[XYZ_ABC_Table1] where [Id]=@Id order by [order]
select top 1 @MinOrder =  [order] from [dbo].[XYZ_ABC_Table1] where [Id]=@Id order by [order] desc

while(@MinOrder<>@MaxOrder1)
BEGIN  

//rest of your code


set @MinOrder=@MinOrder+1
end
```

**assuming that your order is a sequence 1,2,3,4,5 and not 1,3,5,7,8**

Comment: I am getting incorrect syntax on "top". Can you please check again

Comment: i fixed it check again

Answer (score 0):

try with do while loop.

```
declare @MaxOrder1 int=0

select @MaxOrder1 = max([order]) from [dbo].[XYZ_ABC_Table1] where [Id]=@Id
if (@MaxOrder1 is null)
begin

set @MaxOrder1 =0
end
---while loop start
WHILE (@intFlag <=5) -- replace 5 with your limit 
BEGIN
set @MaxOrder1 = @MaxOrder1+1

UPDATE STPC SET STPC.[IsIncluded]= PT.[Value] FROM [dbo].[XYZ_ABC_Table1] STPC  join @Table2 PT on (PT.Id = STPC.Id)  
   UPDATE STPC SET STPC.[Order]= case
                  when STPC.[IsIncluded] = 1 then @MaxOrder1
                  else ''
                  END
                  FROM [dbo].[XYZ_ABC_Table1] STPC  join @Table2 PT on (PT.Id = STPC.Id)

END -- while loop end here
```

Comment: how many rows do you need to update? need your sample data and exact SP.

Comment: the sample data is around 4-5 rows.. and the SP is same as above

Comment: the above stored procedure is being called from a c# code. It works fine if I dont implement while loop

Comment: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. this is the exact error which I get

Comment: you could append; Connection Timeout=30 to your connection string and specify the value you wish. If this property isn't set, the timeout value for the connection is the default value (15 seconds).Moreover, setting the timeout value to 0, you are specifying that your attempt to connect waits an infinite time.